# AMD: performance counter for cycles on TLB miss

Tags: performance, perf, amd-processor, tlb, mmu

I'm looking for AMD specific performance counters which count cycles consumed by page walks when `TLB` misses occur. I know Intel has such metrics available.

But do such exist on AMD? I looked in http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/56255_OSRR-1.pdf but didn't find anything close to what I need.

I also looked in `perf` source code https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/events/amd/core.c#L248 It does not seem to have either.

May be it has different names? Any suggestions?

Comment: "consumed by" - do you mean page walk active and the core is stalled, no uops executing?  Because OoO exec *can* hide some page-walk latency in some cases.  (And if a walk is triggered by TLB prefetch, ideally it fully hides the latency and you get no TLB miss, or one that completes soon enough to not be a problem.  But in practice it's more likely that speculative early pagewalks just shorten the stall time, not fully hide it, especially when OoO exec already has to work to hide other latency.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me you're looking for events similar to Intel's `*.WALK_DURATION` or `*.WALK_ACTIVE` on AMD Zen processors. There are no such events with the same exact meaning, but there are similar events.

The closest events are the IBS performance data fields `IbsTlbRefillLat` and `IbsItlbRefillLat`, which measure the number cycles it takes to fulfill an L1 DTLB or L1 ITLB miss, respectively, in case of miss for the selected instruction fetch or uop. Note that in `perf record`, `IbsTlbRefillLat` can be captured with the `ibs_fetch` PMU and `IbsItlbRefillLat` can be captured with the `ibs_op` PMU.

The event `Core::X86::Pmc::Core::LsTwDcFills` is also useful. It counts the number of L1 data cache fills for page table walks that miss in the L1 for each data source (local L2, L3 on the same die, L3 on another die, DRAM or IO on the same die, DRAM or IO on another die). Walks fulfilled from farther sources are more expensive and would probably have a larger impact on performance. This event doesn't count walks that hit in the L1 data cache, although there are other events that count L2 TLB misses. Also, this event only count for L2 DTLB misses and not ITLB misses.

In current versions of upstream kernel, `LsTwDcFills` is not listed by `perf list` and so `perf` doesn't know the event by name. So you'll have specify the event code using the syntax `cpu/event=0x5B, umask=0x0/`. This event represents any page table walk for a data load or store for which there is an allocated MAB (meaning that the walker missed in the L1D). You can filter the count according to the response by specifying an appropriate umask value as defined in the manual. For example, the event `cpu/event=0x5B, umask=0x48/` represents a walk where the response came from local or remote main memory.

One good approach for utilizing all of these monitoring facilities as a small part of your overall microarchitectural performance analysis methodology is to first monitor `LsTwDcFills`. If it exceeds some threshold compared to the total number of memory accesses (excluding instruction fetches), then capture `IbsTlbRefillLat` for sampled uops to locate where in your code these expensive walks are occurring. Similarly, for instruction fetch walks, use the event `Core::X86::Pmc::Core::BpL1TlbMissL2Hit` for counting total walks and if the count is too large with respect to total fetches, use `IbsItlbRefillLat` to locate where in your code the most expensive walks are occurring.

Comment: Hadi Brais, thank you for the comments. `perf` version I have does not support `ibs_fetch` and `ibs_op` arguments, so I have to enter raw values. I used `libpfm4` to retreive a list of all available events supported by the CPU, however it didn't list `IbsTlbRefillLat` and `IbsItlbRefillLat`.

Comment: @Mark `IbsTlbRefillLat` and `IbsItlbRefillLat` are not really events, So they won't show up in the list of supported events. They are additional information that can be captured with an IBS sample. The `ibs_fetch` and `ibs_op` must be supported unless you're using a very old kernel version. Specify the perf version, the kernel version, your CPU model, and show the output of the command `dir /sys/bus/event_source/devices/`. Show the exact commands and the errors you're getting. (Edit your question to include this information.)